# Add new record to a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, append, associations

I'm using rails 4.1.6
I have a problem creating new records and then saving them. Here are the models:

```
class Function < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theater
  has_many :showtimes, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parsed_show

  validates :theater, presence: :true
  validates :date, presence: :true
end

class Theater < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :functions, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :functions
end

class Showtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :function
  validates :time, presence: true
  validates :function, presence: true
end

showtime = Showtime.new time: Time.current
theater = Theater.first # read a Theater from the database
function = Function.new theater: theater, date: Date.current
function.showtimes << showtime
function.showtimes.count # => 0
```

why is the showtime not being added to the function's showtimes? I need to save the function later with the showtimes with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Function` object hasn't been persisted. You need to make sure that it's persisted (which of course also requires that it be valid) before you can add things to its list of showtimes.

Try saving the function beorehand, and if it succeeds (that is if `function.persisted?` is `true`), it should allow you to `<<` directly into `function.showtimes`, as you like. Alternatively, you can use the `Function#create` class method instead of the `Function#new` class method, since the former automatically persists the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function#create`

```
theater = Theater.first # read a Theater from the database
function = Function.new theater: theater, date: Date.current
function.showtimes.create(time: Time.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check if saving the function also saved the theaters, and even though function.showtimes.count returns 0, the showtimes are saved to the database anyway.

function.showtimes.count returns:

```
=> 0
```

but
function.showtimes returns:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Showtime id: nil, time: "2015-01-09 04:46:50", function_id: nil>]>
```